# Dynamically added object attributes not available

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, async.js

I have an array of Stock objects and try to attach n Report objects to each of the Stock objects:

```
router.get('/stocks', function (req, res, next) {
    Stock.find({}, function (err, stocks) {
        if (err) {
            next(err)
            return
        }

        async.map(stocks, function (stock, callback) {
            Report.find({ 'isin': stock.isin }).sort('-created').limit(10).exec(function (err, reports) {
                if (err) {
                    next(err)
                    return
                }

                stock.reports = reports
                return callback(null, stock)
            })
        }, function (err, stocks) {
            if (err) {
                next(err)
                return
            }

            res.json(stocks)
        })
    })
})
```

What I get is the list of stock objects *without* the reports... What I want is instead the same stocks, but with the additional attribute `reports` set.

Most interesting is the fact, that `console.log(stock)` before and after the assignment `stock.reports = reports` is the same, but `console.log(stock.reports)` delivers the actual array of report objects...

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution in [this other Stackoverflow topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39515087/async-map-not-working-as-expected?rq=1). The solution was the following:

*And because mongoose ignores fields that does not exist in the schema...*

Because the reports object was not in my stock model, mongoose ignored it... The solution was to add it to mongoose:

```
const StockSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    ...
    reports: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed
    },
    ...
})
```

Comment: Or you can `Stock.find().lean().exec(function (err, stocks) { })`

Answer (score 0):

Blind shot: Sometimes the "dot. notation" fails if attribute doesn't exist. You could try:

```
stock['reports'] = reports
```

instead of

```
stock.reports = reports
```

Comment: I think the word "Sometimes"(You have typo in it!) has nothing to do with programming..

Comment: Probably true. But the fact is that "sometimes" happen and I' never seen a clear list of conditions about it. So for me its only another way of saying "spuriously" or "randomly". And excuse me if this is semantically incorrect. English isn't my mother tongue

Comment: [___JavaScript property access: dot notation vs. brackets?___](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried it and it does not change anything. :(